# Why should not a Symfony2 bundle embed third-party libraries

Tags: php, symfony

[Bundle Structure and Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html):

> A bundle should not embed third-party libraries written in JavaScript,
>   CSS, or any other language.

Why shouldn't i create for example a [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap), or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) bundle?

I think it would be easier to maintain if all third-party CSS and JavaScript libraries live in their own bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for one, It's counter-intuitive. Symfony Bundles are for packages of PHP functionality and you're talking about bundling up front-end libraries.

Secondly - why would it be easier? Things like bootstrap and jQuery are *public* resources to begin with - they don't *need* a distributable bundle to achieve high re-use. PHP resources are *not* public and therefore benefit from this type of system.

Comment: Wrong. "A bundle can host ... web resources.".

Comment: It *can*, yes.  But that doesn't mean that it should a) include third-party libraries or b) be *only* web resources.

Comment: Well i meant there's no difference what type of resource it is. A bundle can't contain 3rd party PHP library, too.

Comment: my bootstrap bundle contains not only the css. It comes with twig resources for form generation. bootstrap it self is compiled from less source with Assetic. jQuery is a bad example...

Comment: Look, I'm not going to take took strong a position, here.  I'm just trying to explain why *I* think the Best Practices include this statement.

Answer (score 1):

The chaos comes when two or more bundles uses the same 3rd party library but different versions. A user of your bundle won't be able to choose which library to include and therefore can't use both bundles at the time.

It's fine to store them in a bundle folder if your bundle is a standalone application, i.e. your application's main bundle. For example, [SonataAdminBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle) includes 3rd party libraries: bootstrap.css, qtip, famfamfam icons.

Comment: ok but i won't to create a bundle containing only the 3rd party library. multiple bundles can depend on this bundled 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0):

look at MopaBootstrapBundle https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle it integrates TwitterBootstrap & jQuery lib for you, also HTML5BoilerPlate if you enable initializr addon.

Comment: thx, this is an great example of an bundle that embed third party libraries.